# how to dynamically create excel files with ssis

Tags: excel, ssis

I have set up a sql task that loads the full result set of names into an object variable, I have it connected to a foreach loop that scans the whole object row by row. I'm unsure about the next steps though. If I can create a data flow task and somehow set up the destination variable equal to the for each loop mapping variable that would be nice. Any tips?

Comment: what is in your result object?

Comment: my result object is just a table of one columns and 80 distinct names

Comment: my bad, I mean what are those names used for? is the data for populating or they are table or database name used for dynamic process?

Comment: they are used for populating excel file names

Comment: you mean the names are used for naming excel file? such as `A.xlsx`,`B.xlsx`?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean.

Comment: I will give the answer soon

Comment: Ill wait for the answer.

Comment: What is in the data flow? How is it different for each file? How is the file name important? Does it change the extract?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you described, all you need to do is as following:

1: The `execute SQL task` to return a list of excel file names, which you have already had.

2. Connect the output to `Foreach Loop Container` and starts to iterate each name.
3. Inside the container, the first task you need is `Script Task`, which is used for creating each excel file.
4. I assume that the excel format are the same for all that you need to populate. You need create a new template with desired column header name specified.
5. For that `script task`, take the mapped variable from container as the `read only` variable, you need to create another variable, set it as `read and write`, suppose it is named as `A`;  for storing the dynamic excel file path for each one,and edit the script.
6. If you are familiar with `C#`, it will be easy for you to `Copy` the template for each iterating name.

Code will be like this:

```
Using System.IO;
...
...
...
string source = "C:\\template.xlsx";//need to be a full path
string target = "C:\\" + Dts.Variables["that read only variable"].Value.Tostring() + ".xlsx"
File.Copy(source,target );
Dts.Variables["A"].Value = target;   //important!
```

7. After `Script task`, need a constrained data flow task, inside that, you need a `excel destination`, tricky part is (1): you need set a dynamic `ExcelFile path` from the properties for that `excel connection manager`, I suggest first time use an existing excel for cache the mapping, then for the dynamic connection part, select `A`, which is the `read and write` variable from the `script task`.
8. For populating the data to excel, you need to convert all the `varchar` type to `nvarchar`, this could be done using either `derived column` or `data conversion`
9. Last but not least, set `delay validation` to `TRUE` for both the `connection manager`, `excel destination` and the entire `data flow task`, it is very important for dynamic process.

All above might be a brief explanation, but that is the main idea.

PS: (1)Excel is very picky in SSIS, if you do not have data access engine installed, might not populate the data successfully. for excel it may need `.JET` (older) or `.ACE`(newer) provider.

(2)If your header row is not simply in the 1st row, you might also need to think about `OPENROWSET` properties.

Comment: let me know which step confused you

Comment: I'm not familiar with C#.  Also what is "cache mapping"?

Comment: What is the sql task equivalent of the script task?

Comment: Does the script task correspond to just simply setting up variables?

Comment: for `cache mapping`, I mean , before the dynamic process, 1st time you need to populate to a existing template so that destination would know what is the mapping relationships.

Comment: No, the `Script task` will help you to generate each excel file. (system task)

Comment: Can I generate the file by using the execute sql task?

Comment: No, `execute sql task` will do nothing else but to run the `sql` query

Comment: Ive created the excel tabs with sql task.  Maybe its possible to include a file task?? But i'm not sure how